# Git grep/search a specific branch

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to grep a certain branch. Simple?

To show a specific file in a branch, one would use:

```
git show branch:my_branch bla_sheep.txt
```

Similar syntax is used to diff, etc.

Is there a way to simply grep a branch:

```
git grep branch:my_branch <regex>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**To look at multiple commits, starting at some branch tip and working backwards:** `git grep` can look in any particular *tree* (hence any particular commit since any given commit identifies a particular tree), but to iterate over every commit contained within some branch, you will need to do your own `git rev-list`:

```
git rev-list branch | while read rev; do git grep <regexp> $rev; done
```

for instance (but you may want to fancy this up more so that your grep stops once you've found what you are looking for).

**If you want to look once, at the commit that is the tip of branch `<branch>`, and find (or fail to find) any instances of `<regexp>`,** just do a simple:

```
git grep <regexp> branch
```

The loop form is only for the case where you want to start at that tip commit *and keep working backwards* through previous commits on the branch as well.

Comment: This repeats it for all the commits though. All I care about is just getting one result.

So more like – the last commit from the branch.

Comment: That's why I said you might want to fancy it up.  Note that `git rev-list` lists things in reverse chronological order by default, so if you want the most recent, you simply want to stop once `git grep` finds something.  (It's not documented, but it seems that `git grep` has the same exit status as plain `grep`, i.e., 0 = found something, 1 = didn't.  I didn't test any further.)

Comment: Thanks. I would like to keep this open for a while though.

Answer (score 9):

To grep another branch use:

```
git grep <regex> <branch-name>
```