# How to grep files on another git branch?

Tags: git

I'm on `develop` branch, and I need grep some keyword from files of another branch. Is there any easy way to do it?

I do follow:

```
git stash
git checkout branchXX
grep something -R src/
git checkout develop
git stash pop
```

Is there something like

```
git grep something -R src --branch branchXXX
```

Comment: Have a look at this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661714/git-grep-search-a-specific-branch)

Comment: Try `git grep something branchXXX`